# Sharing Image and Text together is not working for Telegram on android

Tags: java, android, share, telegram

I'm using the code below to share Image and text in Android. When I choose Whatsapp it shares the image and text together , but when I choose Telegram it just shares Image without any text! What's wrong in my code? Tnx

```
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageViewSample .getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmapImg = drawable.getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContext() .getContentResolver(), bitmapImg, "Title", null);
    Uri myUri= Uri.parse(path);
        try {
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);                            
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM , myUri);
            myBodyText="This is a test.";
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , myBodyText);
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            share.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "choose app"));
       } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a NEW File with your PATH passed as an argument, then use the method "fromFile(file name)" from the class Uri(Uniform Resource Identifier) and proceed with your code as usual.

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageViewSample .getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmapImg = drawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContext() .getContentResolver(),bitmapImg, "Title", null);
File myImage = new File(path); // introduce the new File
Uri myUri= Uri.fromFile(myImage); //Pass the file as argument
  try {
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);                            
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM , myUri);
        myBodyText="This is a test.";
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , myBodyText);
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        share.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "choose app"));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. Look my code:

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.insta_image_j);
    Bitmap bitmapImg = drawable.getBitmap();

    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(bitmapImg, context));
    sharingIntent.putExtra(
            android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            context.getString(R.string.share_text));
    sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, context.getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));
```

And I added these lines to Application's onCreate():

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
```